# Python script for opening webpage directly in QGIS

Tags: qgis, python, pyqt4

I have a shapefile with points referring to a webpage with a photograph.

Until now I define an action to open the corresponding webpage in firefox. Eg.
[image]

I have to share my project. Because I don't know the configuration of the receiver I want to create an action in Python to open the webpage into QGIS:
[image]

This works if there is just one point I have to select.  But there are several points that hide each other (more than one picture taken from the same place).

With the 'Generic-action' multiple url's opens into firefox. On the other hand: with the 'python-action' only the first url, lying on top, opens.

I tried following:

```
from PyQt4.QtCore import QUrl
from PyQt4.QtWebKit import QWebView
layer = qgis.utils.iface.activeLayer()
myWV = layer.selectedFeatures()
for f in myWV:
   f = QWebView(None)
   f.load(QUrl(['foto_url']))
   f.show()
```

This does not work.

Comment: You shouldn't change the loop variable (f) inside loop ( f= QWebView(None)). To refer to a column you need a feature f['foto_url']. This action is working for selected item not the  one you clicked on.

Comment: For short term, it's not important but in the future `QtWebKit` module will be removed (e.g http://osgeo-org.1560.x6.nabble.com/Qt4-gt-Qt5-timeline-Qt4-s-status-and-Qt4-s-webkit-removal-in-Stretch-td5203810.html)

Answer (score 1):

A solution was given by Tim Sutton in [A python layer action to open a wikipedia page in QGIS](http://linfiniti.com/2012/03/a-python-layer-action-to-open-a-wikipedia-page-in-qgis/) (in one single line):

In my case, the field is  "URL" and the complete path of one feature is for example

`http:/..../descriptions/4280614.htm (URL = "4280614.htm")`

The Python action is then (in one single line):

```
from PyQt4.QtCore import QUrl; from PyQt4.QtWebKit import QWebView;  myWV = QWebView(None);myWV.load(QUrl('http:/..../descriptions/[% "URL" %]')); myWV.show()
```

You can use this script with a local file (`QUrl.fromLocalFile`):

`/Users/Shared//descriptions/htm/4280614.htm`

```
from PyQt4.QtCore import QUrl; from PyQt4.QtWebKit import QWebView;  myWV = QWebView(None); myWV.load(QUrl.fromLocalFile('/Users/Shared//descriptions/htm/[% "test" %]')); myWV.show()
```

And with an image

```
from PyQt4.QtCore import QUrl; from PyQt4.QtGui import QLabel, QPixmap; label = QLabel(None); pixmap = QPixmap('[% "image" %]'); label.setPixmap(pixmap); label.show()
```

and...

Comment: Hi Gene,  I am using the solution of Tim Sutton in the 'python-action'.  See above.  The problem is that it only opens 1 weblink as there are multiple points at the same place.
.

Comment: normal, QGIS  takes the first point and the first 'foto.url'. Use the [Identify features window](http://docs.qgis.org/2.0/uk/docs/user_manual/introduction/general_tools.html)